# Vortice.Windows: How to call SetSwapChain() in WinUI?

Tags: c#, sharpdx, winui-3

I'm trying to initialize my SwapChainPanel as described [in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.swapchainpanel?view=windows-app-sdk-1.1#initializing-a-swapchainpanel-element) by calling `ISwapChainPanelNative.SetSwapChain()`.

However, I'm struggling to convert my `Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.SwapChainPanel` to `ISwapChainPanelNative`.

How can I get a `ISwapChainPanelNative` from my WinUI `SwapChainPanel`?

What I've tried so far:

```cs
private void AssociateSwapChainPanel(
    Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.SwapChainPanel swapChainPanel,
    Vortice.DXGI.IDXGISwapChain3 swapChain)
{
    IUnknown swapChainPanelUnknown = swapChainPanel as IUnknown; // null
    IInspectable swapChainPanelInspectable = swapChainPanel as IInspectable; // null
    var swapChainPanelNative = swapChainPanel as Vortice.WinUI.ISwapChainPanelNative; // Doesn't compile
    var swapChainPanelNative = swapChainPanelInspectable.ObjRef.AsInterface<Vortice.WinUI.ISwapChainPanelNative>(); // Exception
    var swapChainPanelNative = WinRT.CastExtensions.As<Vortice.WinUI.ISwapChainPanelNative>(swapChainPanel); // Exception
    var swapChainPanelNative = (Vortice.WinUI.ISwapChainPanelNative)(object)swapChainPanel; // Exception
```

Comment: Do you have a small reproducible sample?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I am working with. Hope it helps you if it is still not working.

```
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using SharpGen.Runtime;
using Vortice.Direct3D;
using Vortice.Direct3D11;
using Vortice.DXGI;

class ...
{
    ID3D11Device2 m_Device;
    ID3D11DeviceContext m_DeviceContext;
    SwapChainPanel m_SwapChainPanel;
    readonly IDXGISwapChain2 m_SwapChain;
    
    void ...()
    {
        var swapChainDescription = new SwapChainDescription1()
        {
            AlphaMode = AlphaMode.Ignore,
            BufferCount = 2,
            Format = Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm,
            Height = (int)m_SwapChainPanel.RenderSize.Height,
            Width = (int)m_SwapChainPanel.RenderSize.Width,
            SampleDescription = new SampleDescription(1, 0),
            Scaling = Scaling.Stretch,
            Stereo = false,
            SwapEffect = SwapEffect.FlipSequential,
            BufferUsage = Usage.RenderTargetOutput
        };

        D3D11.D3D11CreateDevice(
            null,
            DriverType.Hardware,
            DeviceCreationFlags.None,
            new[]
            {
                FeatureLevel.Level_11_1,
                FeatureLevel.Level_11_0,
            },
            out var defaultDevice);

        m_Device = defaultDevice.QueryInterface<ID3D11Device2>();
        m_DeviceContext = m_Device.ImmediateContext2;
                    
        using (var dxgiDevice3 = m_Device.QueryInterface<IDXGIDevice3>())
        using (IDXGIFactory2 dxgiFactory = dxgiDevice3.GetAdapter().GetParent<IDXGIFactory2>())
        using (IDXGISwapChain1 swapChain1 = dxgiFactory.CreateSwapChainForComposition(dxgiDevice3, swapChainDescription))
            m_SwapChain = swapChain1.QueryInterface<IDXGISwapChain2>();

        using (var nativeObject = ComObject.As<Vortice.WinUI.ISwapChainPanelNative2>(m_SwapChainPanel))
            nativeObject.SetSwapChain(m_SwapChain);
    }
}
```

Comment: When m_SwapChain is readonly, the sample you posted is actually the constructor right? Because the method starts with a void which would suggest it is not the contructor. Either way, I am getting an DXGI_ERROR_INVALID_CALL when calling CreateSwapChainForComposition so a more complete example would be much appreciated.

Comment: I moved the code to the SwapChainPanel Loaded handler and it works now. The problem was related to the SwapChainPanel Size being 0 in the Constructor.

Comment: I tried to isolate my code. Good to hear you could solve the problem. If you still want to see the complete code of the snippet, here is a link to it: 
https://github.com/CanTalat-Yakan/3DEngine/blob/master/Engine/Assets/Engine/Utilities/Renderer.cs

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated. That might become useful soon when I work more on this project.